# Is there any idiom that means "that's good enough"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Is there any idiom that means "that's good enough"? I thought "that will do" meant that's good enough in that it's good enough for the job, but it seems to mean "there's enough for the job" or "there's enough for me", which is surprising, because I used to use it to mean "That's good enough" Is there any idiom that means "That's good enough", I am looking for a phrase and not a word, and preferably something that doesn't start with "that's" or something similar.

Comment: Although you accepted an answer, the one you accepted has to start with *"that's" or something similar*. (Saying just *up to scratch* is ungrammatical.) So, is that actually not a requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could use [up to scratch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up-to-scratch):

> reaching an acceptable standard

Comment: But how would you express this without putting *"that's" or something similar* in front of it? I can't see how this meets the criteria requested in the question. Simply saying *up to scratch* is ungrammatical.